# Some .htaccess rewrite rules don't work on dev machine only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules (part of a much bigger set)

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login2/?$ login.php [L]
```

The first rule does not work, the second rule does. For some reason, my server does not seem to pick up certain redirection rules such as `login/?` and `tools/?` but minor modifications like adding 1 more character to it seem to "fix" the problem.

Additionally, these rules work on my production server, but I am currently setting up a development environment with vagrant machines. The environments have different linux flavors (debian prod vs ubuntu dev) and may have different versions of apache (? prod, 2.4 dev) but it seems a little funny for this cause such odd behavior with certain `RewriteRule`s.

Comment: @anubhava The .htaccess is alongside these files in the folder being served (the root folder and only vh on the machine). The exact url is `http://local.dev/login` and `http://local.dev/login2`. The files on the server are in the folder `/var/www/local`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, the `/login` gives me my 404 page, the `/login2` gives me the proper page. And there are no other rules for `/login` in my .htaccess file.

Comment: @anubhava Renaming it made both give a 404. Removing all rules except those two, the `RewriteEngine on`, and the `RewriteBase /` give the same results as before (404 on login, page on login2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65653/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ktash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off content negotiation feature of Apache by using:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

on top of .htaccess.  Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.